# Using OSGi services in a mediator

Tags: osgi, wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any way to create a custom mediator that access existing osgi services?

Basically I already have some functionality published as OSGi Services, that I want to be able to call from a custom mediator, but I can't find any way to get access to them.  While the class mediator allows for creating instances of classes exposed through osgi, it doesn't appear to allow for the injection of other osgi services.

Comment: What do you mean by a "custom mediator"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot do it using the class mediator, you can write a complete mediator. It will allow your mediator to access OSGi services as other mediators.

These three blog posts describes how to create a such full featured mediator for WSO2 ESB.

1. [Part 1](http://maninda.blogspot.com/2012/11/writing-custom-mediator-for-wso2-esb.html)
2. [Part 2](http://maninda.blogspot.com/2013/01/writing-custom-mediator-for-wso2-esb.html)
3. [Part 3](http://maninda.blogspot.com/2013/01/writing-custom-mediator-for-wso2-esb_7.html)

And [this](http://achala11.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-write-custom-mediator-wso2-esb.html) is how to create a such mediator using WSO2 Developer Studio.